# Unable to knit to PDF using TinyTeX: Missing *.sty file

Tags: latex, r, pdflatex

I've installed TinyTeX and am now trying to knit the generic "Untitled.Rmd" file to PDF,

```r
> install.packages("tinytex")
> tinytex::install_tinytex()

> options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
> rmarkdown::render("Untitled.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document")
```

which returns this error message:

```r
tlmgr search --file --global "/grffile.sty"
! LaTeX Error: File `grffile.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *>

Error: Failed to compile Untitled.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Untitled.log for more info.
In addition: Warning message:
In parse_packages(logfile, quiet = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)) :
  Failed to find a package that contains grffile.sty
```

I've tried installing the package but that didn't seem to help.

```r
> tinytex::tlmgr_install("grffile")
```

Has anyone else had this issue? I've so far been able to reproduce this error on both Windows and MacOS, when a second LaTeX distribution is not present.

Comment: Thanks for the report! I just fixed the issue in the **rmarkdown** package. Please see https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/152#issuecomment-552501131

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem with pdflatex. Package grffile was updated several days ago, on 2019-11-08. The changelog reveals the cause:

> Recent changes in LaTeX and specifically the release
>            LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 2
>    mean that most of the facilities of grffile are not needed,
>    also the changes mean that some of the original patches
>    made by this package no longer work.
>
> This package is now a legacy package that by default just
>    loads the standard graphicx package.
>
> The LaTeX package rollback feature is enabled so that
>                 \usepackage{grffile}[=v1]
>    may be used to access version 1(.18) of the package if
>    that is needed.`

I removed all references to grffile from my documents and they compile fine now.

Comment: Thank you! And for anyone looking for a fix in the **rmarkdown** package, please see the top comment.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the top of the .rmd file

```
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
```

Comment: I did this but it actually didn't change the error message.

Comment: This is plainly useless and this answer should get downvoted.